# Why does my dynamic import make 2 network request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, dynamic-import

I have a file where I import some css (via raw-loader) and put it in a style tag in the head of my document, then I default export the corresponding react-component.

```js
// Swiper.js
import swiperStyles from '!!raw-loader!swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css';

const swiperElement = document.createElement('style');
swiperElement.innerHTML = swiperStyles;

document.head.append(swiperElement);

export { default } from 'react-id-swiper';
```

When I lazy load this file webpack I get 2 network requests.

```js
const Swiper = import('./Swiper');
```

[image: Network requests in my browser]

The second file only contains the style tag creation and putting it in the head, the css and the code for the react-component are in the first "vendor" file. Why does webpack split it into 2 files and how do I avoid that? I use create-react-app if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

This is because they correspond to two different import, managed separately:

```
export { default } from 'react-id-swiper'; // this will be imported somewhere


import swiperStyles from '!!raw-loader!swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css'; // this is imported and used separately
```

Comment: But why is the css in the same file as the react-component?

Comment: Because it is imported as string (raw loader)

Comment: How do I write this code that I only end up with one file?

Comment: You do not want code that end up in one file. Import are cached so it useful to have reused or reusable code as separate import, as it will be loaded only once.

Comment: When I import `Swiper.js`I want only one file to be requested. Isn't that possible?

Comment: You can give the CommonsChunkPlugin the name of an existing chunk and it will add it to that instead of creating a new file. But, really, why do you want that ?

Comment: Because I don't want to make 2 requests for something which could be resolved in one. Does webpack put imports from the node_modules folder into the vendors file?

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of webpack. Notice that 2 request will be made ONCE even if you reuse multiple time your imports.

Comment: There are two costs that we need to take into account when we talk about performance. The first is the cost to send the code to the user’s browser. The smaller the files we send the faster the user’s browser will receive them.

The second cost is the action that the browser needs to take to parse and execute the JavaScript we’ve sent him. https://hackernoon.com/lessons-learned-code-splitting-with-webpack-and-react-f012a989113

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196202/discussion-between-wavum-and-mose-raguzzini).